# Processing signals with phantom fundamentals

Tags: audio

Is there a formula to calculate the frequency of a [phantom fundamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_fundamental) based on the harmonics, and would this formula be applied directly to the energy bins of an FFT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods for estimating a fundamental pitch frequency (missing or not) from an FFT result containing a series of harmonics include finding maxima in a cepstrum, the harmonic product  spectrum method, and looking for clusters in histograms of the distances between frequency pairs of higher order frequency peaks that fit within psycho-acoustic filter bandwidths..  These are all more estimation algorithms that post-process an FFT result, rather than a simple formula.

Answer (score 2):

AMDF, ASDF, and autocorrelation (all in the time domain) make no assumption about any energy at the fundamental, even though they make some assumption about periodicity.

Comment: But if the fundamental frequency is not present in the signal (not showing up in a plot of the spectrum) how can autocorrelation detect that frequency? :)  This is quite tricky I think. Small experiment. I generated 100 random samples and repeated them 20 times and call the result x.

Comment: If I plot the spectrum and assume fs=10kHz the 100Hz fundamental is clearly showing up. Then I apply a HPF (fc=170) to suppress the fundamental by approx. 40dB. If I plot the time signal the HPF filtered signal is clearly still 100 samples periodic even though the spectrum has very little energy at 100Hz. I wonder what would happen if I nulled out the fundamental completely...